# Using an Artifactory nuget feed in Visual Studio - how to get relevant search results in the package manager?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, artifactory

I've setup a virtual repository in Artifactory to provide access to both nuget.org and and internal nuget feeds.

However when I'm using the virtual repository in Visual Studio (2019 atm), the package manager returns a search result that is not relevant in most cases. The package I need is somewhere in the result, but not at the top. This is even if the package name is unique.

Using Artifactory with virtual repository:
[image: Using Artifactory with virtual repository]

Using nuget.org Directly:
[image: Using nuget.org directly]

In the virtual repository there are options to include or exclude patterns, but I have no idea how to use it to create decent search results in the package manager.

This makes me wonder if there's something I've missed.

Comment: Actually, the search results returned by nuget are sorted by relevance, which is by design and therefore cannot be changed. Or you can reflect your thoughts to [our user voice forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)(suggest a feature) and I hope they will give you satisfactory help.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT I'm not sure that's how it works with Artifactory. We've used ProGet previously and had no issues with relevance with it. So I was surprised when I learned that this can be a problem with an Artifactory setup.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT O

Comment: Actually, this is a quite complex issue and If you combine multiple data sources, the returned results match the returned data in order according to the combined data source, so I think you should suggest a feature on our [Microsoft DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to add that teature.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio's package manager UI has a drop down on the right hand side, above the results, to select which source(s) to search.

If "all" is select, NuGet somehow merges results. I think it maintains server order, but uses some algorithm to decide in which order to merge the multiple result sets.

But if only a single source is selected, then the UI maintains search results order. Therefore it's up to the search server to return results in a good order. If you use Artifactory or Azure Artifacts to aggregate nuget.org and private packages into a single feed, it's up to that feed's search implementation to determine the results order, which might not be the same order as when searching nuget.org directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, it's rather vague and not focusing whether there's something that can be done in Artifactory or Visual Studio for that matter. Yes, you can choose a source in Visual Studio, however, if you're going for a virtual repository where several repositories are bundled together then you don't have that option. Therefore if there's a way to configure the search result coming out of Artifactory, that would be the best approach.

Comment: no, there's nothing that can be done in Visual Studio. We have an [old issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2585) asking to provide different sorting options, but there's been almost no customer engagement, and exactly zero +1 upvotes, so it doesn't seem important. I don't work on Artifactory, or use it, so I don't know if there's anything that can be done to tune the search results it returns. I have no idea if they monitor StackOverflow, so it may be worthwhile giving them feedback more directly.

Comment: I figured as much. Therefore I though that there might be a way to do it in Artifactory.